# components-font-awesome is not been displayed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, font-awesome

I have installed components-font-awesome with bower for my rails application.

I successfully include the sass files,

```
@import "components-font-awesome/scss/fa-brands";
@import "components-font-awesome/scss/fontawesome";
```

Then when I am trying to add an icon to my page

```
<i class="fab fa-facebook-f" style="font-size: 48px;"></i>
```

it's not been displayed.
I am tracing the element on console and looks good.

It has a font-family:

```
Font Awesome 5 Brands';
```

and the right before content

```
content: "\f39e";
```

But still it's not displayed.

Comment: It seems most likely that the cause of the problem is that the webfont files are not loading. Perhaps they are not installed and available through the asset pipeline, or the path is incorrect.

You have specified the icon correctly with your `<i>` tag. 

The `font-family` is correct for the Brands style. 

Also, normally you would specify an icon with _either_ "before content" (pseudo element) _or_ with an `<i>` tag. But you mention both here, which makes me wonder of there's some wire-crossing going on.

Can you verify that the browser is fetching the font files?

Answer (score -1):

Include the class `fa`. It looks like you have used `fab`.

`<i class="fa fa-facebook-f" style="font-size: 48px;"></i>`

Comment: Incorrect. In Font Awesome 5, the prefix for any icon in the Brands style must be 'fab'. The 'fa' prefix is only present in Font Awesome 5 for backwards compatibility and is taken to mean 'fas', the default style. Since there is no 'facebook-f' icon in the 'fas' style, no icon will be found. So, the 'fab' prefix in the code of the original post is correct.